# Javascript - Write Screenwidth Screensize

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to resize a CSS Canvas, and it is controlled with this Javascript currently.

I'm not best at Javascript : but is there a way to get the screenwidth and then just use that data rather than a less than and else.

So say screen size is 390x500. Can I not just get the screen.width and say -5 from it.  Make it that size?  So 390x500 would be '385'.

```
        screenwidth = screen.width;

            if (screenwidth < 400) {
                canvas.width = 375;
                canvas.height = 200;
            } else {
                canvas.width = 500;
                canvas.height = 300;
            }
```

Sorry, I didn't clarify.  This is for sizing a signature pad.  Messing with the CSS or HTML mucks everything.  The sizing is handled within a large Javascript with coordinates etc...

Answer is: 
               canvas.width = screen.width - 5;

Thx, don't know why I didn't see that was what I should have tried.

Comment: `canvas.width = screen.width - 5`?

Comment: *CSS Canvas*? You mean `<canvas>`? That's HTML.

Comment: *Can I not just get the screen.width and say -5 from it. Make it that size? So 390x500 would be '385'.* Have you tried?

Comment: Conditional styles are what [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are for. Also, in CSS, you can just say `canvas { width:calc(100% - 5px); }`, to get your result. No JavaScript needed.

Comment: Phix thx : that worked. I tweaked a bit to be - 25.  But seems to work fine. Dacre - havent tried urs but may.  Its for a signature pad and playing with the CSS wrecks everything.  The width call only seems to work in the Javascript.  Don't know why I didn't see that as plain as day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't clarify. This is for sizing a signature pad. Messing with the CSS or HTML mucks everything. The sizing is handled within a large Javascript with coordinates etc...

Answer is: canvas.width = screen.width - 5;

Thx, don't know why I didn't see that was what I should have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible - you might find `document.body.clientWidth` is more useful for what you are trying to do here, as this will give you the dimensions of your current document (webpage) rather than dimenions of your entire phyiscal display in pixels (ie via `screen`).

So for instance, if you wanted the canvas' width to dynamically update to be 5px less than the current webpage width, you could do this:

```js
function updateCanvasSize() {
  
  var canvas = document.body.querySelector('canvas');
  
  // Set canvas width to document width, minus 5
  canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth - 5;
}

// Causes canvas resize to happen when window is resized
window.addEventListener('resize', updateCanvasSize);

// Init canvas size on startup
updateCanvasSize();
```

```css
canvas {
border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Alternatively, you could take the following pure CSS approach to achieve the same result:

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid red;
  width:calc(100% - 5px);
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: How about just `canvas { width:calc(100% - 5px); }` and be done?

Comment: @ScottMarcus yes, good point - just updated the answer, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Conditional styles are what [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) are for.

And they make the need for JavaScript go away:

```css
/* Default styling: */
canvas { 
  border:2px solid red;
  width:calc(100% - 5px);  /* Does exactly what it looks like it does */
  height:200px;
}

/* Conditional style that only kicks in when the viewport is at least 400px wide              */
@media (min-width:400px){
  canvas { height:300px; }  /* Only define what needs to be changed */
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```